# Overlap detection does not work correctly when there is more than one warrior colliding with the tower

Tags: unreal-4, overlay

I have a project where warriors are generated and they follow a route. In this route has a tower, when a warrior overlaps that tower, it takes 5 of it life, and he does it every 1 second.

**Code of the moment of the collision of the warrior with the tower (Warrior Blueprint): *Call Even Lose Life***

[image]

Look that the moment he overlaps the tower, he starts to move towards it. After that he calls an event that is present in the blueprint of the tower.

**Event that was called (Tower Blueprint): *Execute Event Lose Life and call Event Attack Tower***

[image]

This event causes the life of the tower to be shortened by 5. Soon afterwards it is called an event in the warrior that is colliding with the tower.

**Event called by the tower (Warrior Blueprint): *Execute Event Attack Tower and Call Event Lose Life***

[image]

This event is only to be given a 1 second interval between each attack by each warrior. At least that was the idea.

I could simply loop in the blueprint of the tower and multiply the damage (5) by the amount of warriors colliding, but it does not seem right to me.

I imagine the problem is because the event in the tower (**image 2 of question**) is being called multiple times without even being finalized.

**In the game, when there is only one warrior overlapping the tower, everything happens correctly:**

[image]

1 second interval between images.

**With more than one warrior overlapping the tower, tower life only decreases with the arrival of a new warrior. While a new warrior does not come to life he remains intact:**

[image]

**When in reality what should happen was each of them take 5 life per second. Then 3 warriors, 15 life per second.**

The way I did these 15 lifetimes will not be taken away at the same time, as the warriors have come at different times.

**Exemplifying:**

- Warrior 1 arrived in the tower at 15.2 seconds.
- Warrior 2 arrived in the tower at 21.5 seconds.
- Warrior 3 arrived in the tower at 32.8 seconds.

**Then in the second 33 (moment where the three warriors have already arrived):**

- Warrior 1 will take 5 life from the tower at 33.2 seconds.
- Warrior 2 will take 5 life from the tower at 33.5 seconds.
- Warrior 3 will take 5 life from the tower at 33.8 seconds.

*How to make the damage to the tower correctly applied, regardless of the amount of warriors?*

---

**EDIT 1 (Attempt made based on Stephen's answer)**

**Warrior Blueprint:**

[image]

It works perfectly when it is colliding with only one warrior, when it reaches 1 more, life stops to decrease and decreases 5 for each new warrior that overlaps.

---

**EDIT 2 (getting deeper into the tests)**

**Pretty much the same code as the first edition, with the difference that I added a print at the end of the loop (when it is finalized) and added another condition to take the test:**

[image]

In the print will appear the actor's name + the word "acabou" + condition value.

**In Game:**

[image]

As soon as the second warrior overlaps the tower, the loop of the first and second warrior ends. This happens with both conditions.

***The loop is ending incorrectly and I do not know why. Something is making the condition false.***

**Message Log:**

[image]

Comment: Whats “ atacar  torre “ ? wWhat exact event is that ? Whats perder vilda ?

Comment: Sorry ColdSteel. I am not English speaker, so when I "program" I name the events in my language. Atacar Torre => Attack Tower and Perder Vida => Lose Life

Comment: I dont get the problem, can you explain what do you expect to happen and what is happening?

Comment: From your desired behavior explanation I can only say that: you have 2 events for overlaps: BeginOverlap and EndOverlap (dont recall the exact names, but thats how it works) -  now BeginOverlap will only be called once the Actor/Character starts to overlap please note ONCE :)

Comment: Now the event will be called once for each character contains only the Characters data (hit result) in it.  To know how many characters are overlaping the turret: you have to add them i. To an array (BeginOverlap -> AddUnique to your array and on endOverlap remove it) this way you will always know hiw many characters are overlapping the Turret.

Comment: Now inside your turret you can just loop the array once 5 secs and decrease turrets HP like TurretHP -= OverlappingCharacters.Num()*-5.0f;

Comment: If you want to decrease HP (“async like”) based on each Character’s arrival time - you can just open up a Timer for each character and loop it until Character stops overlapping (dies, runs away, you call).

Comment: The way I did, I was thinking that more than one character could call a single event. In case this tower event (Lose Life). But it looks like there are problems, as I imagine it can not be called an event that is already running.

Comment: The event is not continuous, it is fired once per overlap. This is intended behavior. I mean it is not running, its just called once an overlap state of the actors changed. It won’t tick all the time actor is overlapping.

Comment: Thinking of something like what I want. The minions of the League of Legends or Dota 2. It seem to deal damage to the towers independently of each other. The moment each of them attacks varies.

Comment: Yes, that's why I did one scheme of one event by calling the other.

Comment: Lose Life call Attack Tower and Attack Tower call Lose Life, until the tower is destroyed.

Comment: Video showing the minions hitting a tower => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcbFIPC5OQE

Comment: In LOL they running their own logic/AI state machine - the attck starts once a minion arrive to target or it decides to attack someone - so they start at different times, then each of them waits for the amount between attack (whether in tick or on timers I dont know) - so you have nice flow for each character (minion).

Comment: If I change the damage event applied to the tower for each minion, do I get the expected result? That is, if the event that defines the damage that the tower receives is executed on each minion, instead of each minion call the event that damages the tower in the blueprint of the tower.

Comment: I dont know what do you mean. If you want to achieve something like in LOL you will have to run the logic on minions.

Comment: Minion will have states e.g. walking/idle/attacking will have its target (tower in your case, but better to make it as an interface and let tower to derive from targetable/attackable/damageble interfaces. In minion’s tick or BehaviorBP you will query the state if the state is attacking you will execute the attacking logic in this case make the turret 5 hp less.

Comment: What you said to me in the last comment seemed interesting to me, and I intend to do it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables that prevent the event from being called more than once. That's the secret.

So when calling the event you impose conditions that (visually) the overlap never closes.

In fact, it will be oscillating.

To solve this, as soon as the warrior overrides the tower, have him try to go towards it (simple move to location/actor) until he dies or the tower is destroyed.

**The code is very simple:**

[image]

You use a loop with conditions (see in the image).

Unfortunately I had to use two variables, instead of using only the life of the tower, because it was giving error.

Basically, because Event Tick of the tower, which destroys her as soon as her life arrives. Then I gave the reference error...

Being straightforward, before the tower is destroyed, it defines this Boolean variable as true, thus closing the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The overlap event is working correctly.  Your tower doesn't know how many warriors are attacking it, just that something is inside the detection area.

You could try moving the -5 logic to after the branch of your loop where you check for a warrior but I'm not certain if that would work.

The easiest way would be to put the damage inside the warrior blueprint, casting to the tower so they each (after checking the tower still exists so you don't get nullptr errors) do damage rather than having the tower do all the work.  This way, it doesn't matter if you've got 1 warrior or 1000 attacking.

Comment: Could this verification of the tower's existence be made in what form? Could I use "is valid?" Is there a function that asks if the actor still exists? I did not want to do a check based on the value of tower life.

Comment: I decided to use the function Is Overlapping Actor.